# Como fazer um texto sobrepor uma div com imagem?

Tags: html, css

Não consigo fazer o texto "Texto que quero sobrepor." ficar em cima da div "textDiv" que esta com uma imagem como background, me ajudem por-favor.

HTML

```
<div class="divLeft">
    <img id="photo" src="photo.png">

    <div class="textDiv">
        <h2><i id="spaceText" class="fas fa-search"></i>Texto que quero sobrepor.</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.divLeft {
    width: 49.5%;
    height: 949px;
    float: left;
}

#spaceText {
    padding-right: 16px;
}

#photo {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 949px;
}
```

Comment: A div não tem imagem como background.

Comment: tente usar um z-index no texto que você quer sobrepor

Comment: "_ficar em cima da div "textDiv"_"... o texto está dentro da div... como assim _ficar por cima_?

Comment: eu quero que o texto fique por cima da imagem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque `position: absolute` na `div .textDiv` e `position: relative` na `div .divLeft`. Aí você posiciona como quiser com com `top` e `left`.

Lembrando que a imagem não é um *background*, é apenas uma imagem normal e você estará posicionando uma camada (a `div .textDiv`) sobre ela.

```css
.divLeft {
    width: 49.5%;
    height: 949px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#spaceText {
    padding-right: 16px;
}

#photo {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 949px;
}

.textDiv{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   
   /*cor apenas para exmplo*/
   color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="divLeft">
    <img id="photo" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">

    <div class="textDiv">
        <h2><i id="spaceText" class="fas fa-search"></i>Texto que quero sobrepor.</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```